# What conditions on primes makes it non principal?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathfrak{p}$  is prime of $K$ what condition I can have on $\mathfrak{p}$ so it becomes non-principal ideal?

Comment: What sort of condition are you looking for? I mean for example tautologically $\mathfrak p$ gives a non-zero class in $\mathrm{Pic}(O_K)$ and by class field theory this happens if and only if $\mathfrak p$ doesn't split completely in the Hilbert class field of $K$. Or you are rather interested how to check non-principality in practice?

Comment: @SUNILPASUPULATI By standard Minkowski-type considerations if there is a principal generator for the ideal you will be able to find it inside a "box" of explicit bounded size. Then for every given element of your ideal lying in the box you can check explicitely whether it generates your ideal or not. This is not very efficient but nevertheless working strategy.

Comment: If you're interested in checking a large number of split primes then maybe the most efficient way is to compute an equation for a generator of the Hilbert class field. Split primes are principal if and only if they remain split in this field, so you're looking for roots of this polynomial mod $p$, and then you can take the gcd with $x^p-x$ to quickly see if there are roots.

Comment: If you're looking for an algorithm, then this is covered in Section 6.5.5 of Henri Cohen's "Course in computational algebraic number theory", in particular the first five steps of Algorithm 6.5.10.  The first step is to compute the class group of K.